# java mysql select statement not returning full date

Tags: java

I'm a java newbie but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.  When I try to retrieve the last two dates from a database it only displays the year(while in mysql the same command provides the correct result).

Mysql command: `SELECT DISTINCT date From fundanalysis ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 2`

Expected result:

```
2011-06-13
2011-06-08
```

Here's my java code:

```
        preparedStatement = con.prepareStatement("SELECT DISTINCT date From fundanalysis ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 2");
        ResultSet numberofrowsresultset = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
        numberofrowsresultset.next();
        // most recent date
        currentdate.add(numberofrowsresultset.getInt("date"));
        System.out.print(numberofrowsresultset.getInt("date"));
        numberofrowsresultset.next();
        // last date before most recent
        currentdate.add(numberofrowsresultset.getInt("date"));
        return currentdate;
```

The final result is: `[2011, 2011]`

I basically want the exact same result as I get when I run the mysql query because I have to submit it as is to do another query later in the program.

pls help!

Comment: Don't use preparedStatement for select query instead use `java.sql.Statement`.

Comment: @Harry Joy: Do you have an explanation (with references) for your assertion?

Comment: @mellamokb: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343730/when-to-use-statement-over-prepared-statement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it is `.getDate` not `.getInt`

try:

```
numberofrowsresultset.getDate("date");
```

Comment: omg thank you so much.  I must be sleepy or something, I forgot about that.  Thanks so much zomboid.

Answer (score 2):

Try use `.getDate()` instead of `.getInt()`:

```
currentdate.add(numberofrowsresultset.getDate("date"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using `.getInt` which returns a numerical value.  You need to use `.getDate` instead when you are getting a date value:

```
System.out.print(numberofrowsresultset.getDate("date"));
                                          ^^^^ change Int to Date
```

Answer (score 1):

Date is not an integer so your '.getInt("date")' method is not returning the result you expect.

You need

```
java.sql.Date myDate = numberofrowsresultset.getDate("date");
```