# Statement and PreparedStatement in JDBC

Tags: java, sql, jakarta-ee, prepared-statement

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference between Statement and PreparedStatement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3271249/difference-between-statement-and-preparedstatement)

I have confused with Statement and PreparedStatement in JDBC.Is PreparedStatement is version of Statement? or any other difference in that ? Can any body clear that question. thanks.

Comment: What happened to Google.com?

Answer (score 2):

From [Using Prepared Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) of the Java official tutorials

> Sometimes it is more convenient to use a PreparedStatement object for
>   sending SQL statements to the database. This special type of statement
>   is derived from the more general class, Statement, that you already
>   know.
>
> If you want to execute a Statement object many times, it usually
>   reduces execution time to use a PreparedStatement object instead.
>
> The main feature of a PreparedStatement object is that, unlike a
>   Statement object, it is given a SQL statement when it is created. The
>   advantage to this is that in most cases, this SQL statement is sent to
>   the DBMS right away, where it is compiled. As a result, the
>   PreparedStatement object contains not just a SQL statement, but a SQL
>   statement that has been precompiled. This means that when the
>   PreparedStatement is executed, the DBMS can just run the
>   PreparedStatement SQL statement without having to compile it first.
>
> Although PreparedStatement objects can be used for SQL statements with
>   no parameters, you probably use them most often for SQL statements
>   that take parameters. The advantage of using SQL statements that take
>   parameters is that you can use the same statement and supply it with
>   different values each time you execute it. Examples of this are in the
>   following sections.