# Exception while input a date into a MySQL database

Tags: java, mysql, date

I have a `MySQL` database and want to write a row into it. The problem is that `MySQL` do not like my `query`, why? This is my **code**:

```
java.sql.Timestamp date = new java.sql.Timestamp(new java.util.Date().getTime());

for (Integer articlevalue : articlesendlist) {
    for (Integer suppliervalue : suppliersendlist) {
        connection.executeQuery("INSERT INTO Bestellungen(Bestellung_ID, Artikel_ID, Lieferant_ID, Datum, Preis) VALUES (" + maxorder + ", " + articlevalue + ", " + suppliervalue + ", " +  date + ", NULL)");
    }
}
```

A small description for my code. The `articlesendlist` contains IDs from selected values from a `JTabel`. The same applies to the `suppliersendlist`. I want to write the IDs into the table "`Bestellung`". The variable `maxorder` is the current ID for the table "`Bestellung`".

If you need it, the **exception** is:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '12:45:06.164, NULL)' at line 1

*Please do not comment/answer with other links, I already searched for the problem and read several sites. They do not help me or are not suitable for my problem.*

- Thank you for help

Comment: First of all, use `PreparedStatemens` to create and execute your query as your way is prone to SQL injections.

Comment: can you post the executed query statement? - missed to escape the date? id is int or varchar? try this: connection.executeQuery("INSERT INTO Bestellungen(Bestellung_ID, Artikel_ID, Lieferant_ID, Datum, Preis) 
VALUES (" + maxorder + ", " + articlevalue + ", " + suppliervalue + ", '" +  date + "', NULL)");

Comment: @svz You cant even know if I use them or not. I wrote myself a Method and you cant know what I m using in there...

Comment: Could the downvoter explain pls?

Comment: @Gerret, I do know that you are not using a `PreparedStatement` from the fact that you use `String` concatenation to build your query.

Comment: @svz hmm okok and what does that? `Statement query = connection.createStatement();`

Comment: @svz would be kind if you could anwer my question. I want to know the diffrence

Comment: @Gerret, that is a simple `Statement`. See this link for `PreparedStatement`: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html and this one also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3271249/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing this line:

```
connection.executeQuery("INSERT INTO Bestellungen(Bestellung_ID, Artikel_ID, Lieferant_ID, Datum, Preis) VALUES (" + maxorder + ", " + articlevalue + ", " + suppliervalue + ", " +  date + ", NULL)");
```

to this:

```
connection.executeQuery("INSERT INTO Bestellungen(Bestellung_ID, Artikel_ID, Lieferant_ID, Datum, Preis) VALUES ('" + maxorder + "','" + articlevalue + "','" + suppliervalue + "','" +  date + "','NULL')");
```

Comment: Yes you are right :) but why is that? What was the mistake? Why I have to put "'"? ^^

Answer (score 1):

Exception is obvious isn't it.

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '12:45:06.164, NULL)' at line 1

You are not using quotes around date field.

However you should really avoid executing your SQL queries like this and use [**`PreparedStatemens`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) for this purpose.

**`PreparedStatemens`** has specific methods like `setDate`, `setTime`, `setLong`, `setString` etc and you don't need to worry about putting right quotes in your code.

Comment: Amm maybe it is for you obvious, not for me thats why I asked here. And with that code I posted, you are not able to know if I use PreparedStatement or not. I wrote a method and there I use them... this method is called executeQuery

Comment: You are calling `executeQuery` by manipulating String and that will require you to use quotes around date value in your insert SQL statement.

Comment: ?? I dont understand that comment now. That makes no sense to my previus comment.

Comment: Accepted answer is also doing the same i.e. putting quotes around inserted values.

Comment: ... Yes I know thats the reason why I accept it. But it dosent change something on it that your comments dosent have a conenction, but ok

Comment: That answer has **exactly followed** what I recommended in my answer: `You are not using quotes around date field.`

Comment: Yes but he was faster... so I accept him and I dosent said that your answer is wrong I already said 3 times that your comments doesent have a connectino and I dont know why you wrote this. At my first comment I was talking about the prepared statements...