# Operation not allowed after ResultSet Closed error Netbeans MySQL Connectivity

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

I am creating a program to rename databases in mysql.
I have succeeded in everything and it successfully happens. But in the end of my script, its shows an error/exception saying "Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed". I really have no idea why this error appears even after researching about this error.
Although the full operation is successfully completed and the database is renamed.
Here is my code->

```
String x = (String) jComboBox1.getSelectedItem(); //jComboBox1 contains the name of current database selected
String z = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter new name for Database"); //Where user enters the name for new database.
new CustComm().setVisible(false);    //Frame that carries the names of tables.
        try{
        Class.forName("java.sql.DriverManager");
        Connection con = (Connection)
        DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:"+GlobalParams.portvar+"/",""+k,""+j);
        Statement stmnt = (Statement) con.createStatement();
        String query = "use "+x;
        stmnt.executeQuery(query);
        String query2 = "show tables";
        ResultSet rs = stmnt.executeQuery(query2);
        while (rs.next()){ 
        String dname = rs.getString("Tables_in_"+x);
        if(CustComm.jTextArea1.getText().equals("")){
        CustComm.jTextArea1.setText(CustComm.jTextArea1.getText()+dname);
        }
        else{
            CustComm.jTextArea1.setText(CustComm.jTextArea1.getText()+"\n"+dname);
        }
        String y = CustComm.jTextArea1.getText();
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(y);
while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = scanner.nextLine();
        String query3 = "Create database "+z;
        stmnt.executeUpdate(query3);
        //alter table my_old_db.mytable rename my_new_db.mytable
        String query4 =  "RENAME TABLE "+x+"."+line+" TO "+z+"."+line;
        stmnt.executeUpdate(query4);
        String query5 = "drop database "+x;
        stmnt.executeUpdate(query5);
}}}

    catch(Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,e.getMessage());
    }
```

Please help.

Comment: instead of e.getMessage use e.printstacktrace and post the error message.Also point out in which line it gives the exception

Comment: Hi and thanks for reply. It throws the following error then (sorry error is too long to be posted here so I gave link)-> http://pastebin.com/wt7UwwuE I am unable to determine the line causing this error :/ Even tried reading and following the error it gave, but no help. It has been a day since I am facing this error and I posted here after my best tries to remove it. Since I am quite new to java, I am unable to figure such error causing line out :( Please help. And yeah, one more thing, the coding for this purpose starts at line 443 and ends at 478.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't execute new queries on statement `Statement stmnt = (Statement) con.createStatement();` while you use `ResultSet` from it, because this will close your `ResultSet`.

> By default, only one ResultSet object per Statement object can be open
>   at the same time. Therefore, if the reading of one ResultSet object is
>   interleaved with the reading of another, each must have been generated
>   by different Statement objects. All execution methods in the Statement
>   interface implicitly close a statment's current ResultSet object if an
>   open one exists.

You should create 2 different statements: first for query2 and second for queries 3-5.

Also it's better to use PreparedStatement. You can read about the difference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3271249/difference-between-statement-and-preparedstatement).

Comment: Thanks!! It was a great help

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to do this work via code?  Have you looked into tools like [Liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org/)?