# java.sql.SQLException: Exhausted Resultset error

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, resultset

I'm facing the problem with this exception **java.sql.SQLException: Exhausted Resultset** in following code. I'm sure my query returns only one value. Even If I don't use **rs.next();** it throws the error  **java.sql.SQLException: ResultSet.next was not called**. Could you please help?

FYI, I'm using the another result set in main where this menthod from another class is called. will it affect?

Thanks

```
public static String getdispname(Connection conn, String resname) 
throws SQLException, Exception {

            //String resname = "";
            String returnValue = "";
            String querystring = "";

            //Query to select the displayname from resid

            querystring += "select distinct display_name";
            querystring += " from cust_rally_team_member";
            querystring += " where display_name like '%"+ resid +"%'";

            // Create select statement
            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();

            try {
                // Execute statement
                ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(querystring);
                if (rs!= null) { 
            while (rs.next()) {
            returnValue = rs.getString("display_name");
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                throw new SQLException(ex);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                throw new Exception(ex);
            }
            // Close statement
            finally {
                stmt.close();
            }

            return returnValue;
```

Comment: Hi guys, Thanks for all your answers. I think the result set has no value. I believe `querystring += " where display_name like '%resid%'";` may not work with like statement with a parameter. Correct me If I'm wrong

Comment: Check whether your sql query with like does return any rows in backend.

Comment: By the way on a separate note, `statement` you are closing in `finally`, similarly do not forget to close `resultset` and `connection`. It is very important.

Comment: Yes its providing the one result as expected. But when I add it in Java, it dont give result. When I replace variable %resid% in the query to %amit%, it provides value. Is the query string the correct reprsentation?

Comment: Ah, so `resid` is a variable declared?

Comment: its the parameter got from main class?

Comment: Then try as `like '%+resid+%'";`.

Comment: I'm sorry it didn't work

Comment: Found the correct statement '%"+ resid +"%', this solved the issue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try as

```
if (rs! = null) { 
 while (rs.next()) {
  returnValue = rs.getString("display_name");
}
......
```

Comment: Got the error ** Uncompilable source code - incompatible types
  required: boolean
  found:    java.sql.ResultSet**

Comment: for the above code you should use while(rs.hasNext()) because while expects boolean but you have passed rs.next() which returns resultset so its not matching and hence the compile time error..change it to rs.hasNext()

Comment: @user1763507 `java.sql.ResultSet` does not have a `hasNext()` method, and `next()` does return a boolean.

Comment: @user2335123 Post your modified code by editing your question so that others would be able to point out what causing the error.

Comment: Thanks @Polppan. I used your  resultset statement and modified my like statement. I updated my code with the updates as advised

Comment: @user2335123 Glad I could help. Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3271249/difference-between-statement-and-preparedstatement) as well.

Comment: Sure will use Prepared statement. Thanks for the hint

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
returnValue = rs.next() ? rs.getString("display_name") : null;
```

You don't need to check if the `rs` is null.  It won't be - assuming the `executeQuery()` returned rather than raising an exception.  (Though the returned result set might have 0 rows).

You also don't need to loop over the result set, assuming you *really* know that you expect back a single row.  (Though, given the query, that seems unlikely.)

Answer (score 0):

use  by your modification like below

```
if (rs != null && rs.first()) {
    do {
        returnValue = rs.getString(("display_name");
    } while (rs.next());
}
```

Comment: Duplicate of your other answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23219863/466862 and still as wrong as `first()` may throw an exception when called on a forward-only result set.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Oracle 10g database , i found same error "java.sql.SQLException: Exhausted Resultset error".  I just grant permission in database and solved my probblem.

SQL> grant insert,update,delete on "table-name" to "database_name";