# Inserting value into a single column in MySQL using Java

Tags: java, mysql, sql

i'm a novice programmer and following is a part of my code to insert data into the database whose name is **book_details**.

```
 try{
  //STEP 2: Register JDBC driver
  Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

  //STEP 3: Open a connection
  System.out.println("Connecting to database...");
  conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,USER,PASS);

  //STEP 4: Execute a query
  System.out.println("Creating statement...");
  stmt = conn.createStatement();
  String sql;
  sql = "INSERT INTO issue_details VALUES("+BookIDvar+",'"+StudentIDvar+"','"+StudentNamevar+"')";
  stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
  sql = "INSERT INTO book_details (book_status) VALUES ('notavailable') WHERE book_id = "+BookIDvar+"";
// there are 4 fields in the database. I wish to insert the string 'notavailable' into the 4th field which is named book_status for a particular BookID
  stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
  //STEP 6: Clean-up environment

  stmt.close();
  conn.close();
 }catch(SQLException se){
  //Handle errors for JDBC
  se.printStackTrace();
 }catch(Exception e){
  //Handle errors for Class.forName
  e.printStackTrace();
 }finally{
  //finally block used to close resources
  try{
     if(stmt!=null)
        stmt.close();
  }catch(SQLException se2){
  }// nothing we can do
  try{
     if(conn!=null)
        conn.close();
  }catch(SQLException se){
     se.printStackTrace();
  }//end finally try
 }
```

Here i intend to update the status of a library book available and not available. I prefer non - Boolean value for some other reasons.

After the execution the **book_details** database is not updated. It also gives an error

`MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server` .

Is there something wrong with the Sql statement or is it something else? Other operations on the same database in other locations are working fine.

Comment: Which of those two queries is failing? and given that you're wide open for [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com), no surprise that it's not working.

Comment: I guess that book_status is a string?  Probably not the issue, but did you try adding a semi-colon at the end of each Statement?

Comment: @archer semi colon is already there i think

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Luggi mentioned that is incorrect.

```
update book_details set book_status = 'notavailable' where book_id = bookIDvar;
```

assuming it already exists in the table.

If not,

```
insert into book_details (book_id, book_status) values (bookIDvar, 'notavailable');
```

Answer (score 4):

This SQL syntax is wrong:

```sql
INSERT INTO <table> VALUES <values> [WHERE <whatever>]
```

You cannot add a `WHERE` in an `INSERT` like that.

The only case to add a `WHERE` statement in an `INSERT` would be when inserting data from the result of a `SELECT` statement and the `WHERE` is part of the `SELECT`. For example:

```sql
INSERT INTO <table> [SELECT <columns> FROM <tables> WHERE <conditions>]
```

In this form, the columns obtained in the `SELECT` must match with the values to insert in the table.

Looks like you want to **update** the status of the book. You should use `UPDATE` statement instead of `INSERT`:

```sql
UPDATE <table> SET (<column> = <value>) (supports multiple columns) WHERE <conditions>
```

Applying this to your context, the statement should be:

```sql
UPDATE book_details SET book_status = 'notavailable' WHERE book_id = ?
```

Also, since this is an *all or nothing* transaction, you should open the transaction and commit if all the statements where executed successfully, otherwise perform a rollback. Here's how you may do it:

```
try {
    conn.setAutoCommit(false);
    //perform the DML statements
    //...
    //commit the transaction
    conn.commit();
} catch (Exception e) {
    //in case of error, rollback the transaction
    conn.rollback();
    //notify the error
    e.printStacktrace();
} finally {
    //ALWAYS close the connection here
    //handle the exceptions and such
    conn.close();
}
```

---

Note that when you need to pass arguments to your SQL statements, you should use `PreparedStatement` instead of `Statement` since concatenating the query could lead to [SQL Injection attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). The code should look like:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO issue_details VALUES(?, ?, ?)";
PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
pstmt.setString(1, BookIDvar);
pstmt.setString(2, StudentIDvar);
pstmt.setString(3, StudentNamevar);
pstmt.executeUpdate();
//similar for other SQL statements
```

More info:

- [Difference between Statement and PreparedStatement](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3271249/1065197)

Comment: where should i add the values then ?

Comment: @SoorajChandran it is unclear what you're trying to achieve. Please provide the functional requirement along to the execution of your queries to provide specific guidance.