# Difference between Statement And PreparedStatement acc to given condition

Tags: java, jdbc

Most relational databases handles a JDBC / SQL query in four steps:

1. Parse the incoming SQL query
2. Compile the SQL query
3. Plan/optimize the data acquisition path
4. Execute the optimized query / acquire and return data

could someone explain me these steps in these following code

```
Statement st=con.createStatement();
ResultSet rset=st.executeQuerry("Select * from tab");

PrepareStatement stm=con.preparedStatement("select * from tab");
ResulSet rset=stm.executeQuerry();
```

what difference acc to above will be in these?

Comment: What does "acc" mean?

Answer (score 0):

`PrepareStatement`are pre compiled and thus it will be faster. Notable difference comes when you have where conditions in select statement, with `Statement` sql queries are subject to SQL Injection whereas using `PrepareStatement` one is safe from  SQL Injection.

The same applies when you have DML statements like `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE` etc.

You can find more details https://stackoverflow.com/a/13245124/599528

Answer (score 0):

`Prepared Statement` queries are pre-compiled on database and there access plan will be reused to execute further queries which allows them to execute much quicker than normal queries generated by `Statement` object.

`Prepared Statement` also allows you to write dynamic and parametric query.Using parametric queries and `PreparedStatement` you prevent many forms of SQL injection because all the parameters passed as part of place-holder will be escaped automatically by JDBC Driver.

Answer (score 0):

Difference will be visible in terms of multiple invocation, as `PreparedStatements` are stored in a pre-compiled format, if the driver supports precompilation, then the `con.preparedStatement("select * from tab");` will send the the statement to the database for precompilation. You can see the difference here :

[http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#createStatement()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#createStatement%28%29)

[http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#prepareStatement(java.lang.String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#prepareStatement%28java.lang.String%29)