# Why does MySQL complain about an unknown column in this query?

Tags: java, mysql, database

I am getting following error while I try to use mysql query

```
Problem in Query
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'abc123' in 'where clause'
```

This is what I am using

```
public Student validate_Student(String s, String t) {

    Student obj = new Student();

    int w = Integer.parseInt(s);

        String query = "SELECT s.* FROM student s JOIN login l on s.id = l.Student_ID WHERE l.Student_ID = " + w + " and l.Password= " + t;

        try
        {
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
            while (rs.next()) {
                obj.setID(rs.getString("ID"));
                obj.setName(rs.getString("NAME"));
                obj.setAddress(rs.getString("ADDRESS"));
                obj.setPhone(rs.getString("PHONE_NO"));
                obj.setEmail(rs.getString("EMAIL"));
                obj.setDOB(rs.getString("DOB"));
                obj.setDegree(rs.getString("DEGREE"));

            }

        }
        catch(SQLException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Problem in Query");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
    return obj;
}
```

Comment: Your problem would be solved if you used parameterized queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with replacing the following line.

```
String query = "SELECT s.* FROM student s JOIN login l on s.id = l.Student_ID WHERE l.Student_ID = " + w + " and l.Password = '" + t +"'";
```

**UPDATE :** You should use `PrepareStatement` instead of `Statement` in above example, which will help you to handle this kind of situations easily.

Also, there are more [**Advantages of Prepare Statement**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3273378/1326692).

[**Prepare Statement Demo**](http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-preparestatement-example-select-list-of-the-records/)

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but it didn't work same error, (I have tried with datatype of Password in Login table as both text and varchar(75) but still gives me same error

Comment: This is what I am using to get text from Passwordfield

String w = String.valueOf(passwordField.getPassword());

Comment: @DanishAli I think you missed the extra single quotes in this answer if you say it didn't work.

Comment: @Danish, if it works you should upvote the answer and also mark it as accepted, so it can helps to others  :)