# no message dialog for deleted from database

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

[image][image]
I want to delete a record from database. The code runs fine, but even when there is a record for a particular id, the message returns `id not found in database`. Please help me to improve my code to display a separate message when id is not found in database.i have attached my output. as u can see id=19 i there in database but when i delete id=19, that particular id record gets deleted from the database but message pops up saying id not found in database.

```
try {
                                    String s = TUID.getText( );
                                    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection( "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql", "root", "root" );
                                    Statement st = con.createStatement( );
                                    String r = "delete from mysql57.addressbook where iid = "+s;
                                    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = con.prepareStatement( r );
                                    preparedStatement.executeUpdate( );
                                    int rows = preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
                                 if(rows == 0)
                        {  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( f, "ID NOT FOUND IN DATABASE");



                        }

                        else{
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( f, "DELETED FROM DATABASE" );

                        }

                                    }


                                }
                                catch (Exception ex) {
                                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( f,ex );
                                }
```

Answer (score 2):

The `executeUpdate()` method returns the amount of rows affected. If no rows were deleted, it returns `0` (naturally).

So...

```
int rows = preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
if(rows == 0)
    ...
else
    ...
```

You should also use `PreparedStatement` correctly, and change that `+ s` into a placeholder (it's amazing how every single tutorial seems to abuse `PreparedStatement` and teach bad habits).

Comment: Some bedtime reading: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3271249/difference-between-statement-and-preparedstatement

Comment: String r = "delete from mysql57.addressbook where iid = " + s;
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = con.prepareStatement( r );
preparedStatement.executeUpdate( );
int rows = preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
if(rows == 0){  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( f, "ID NOT FOUND IN DATABASE" ); }                            else{
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( f, "DELETED FROM DATABASE" );
                            }

FOR BOTH ID MATCHED AN NOT MATCHED . I AM GETTING AN MESSAGE "ID NOT FOUND IN DATABASE".

Comment: Then the id doesn't match.

Comment: When id is matching the same message pops up showing ID not found

Comment: Edit the question and include the code in there, you can see how illegible code is in comments.

Comment: If `rows == 0`, then nothing was deleted, meaning your delete statement didn't match anything in the database.

Comment: yes you are right but if the id matches then else block should be executed and message "id deleted from database '' should be shown,but this is not happening.

Comment: It's not happening because the id doesn't match. If the id did match, then you would get the "id deleted" message. This is a **fact**. It doesn't matter if you say that the id matches, the code says that it doesn't match.

Comment: that particular id record gets deleted from the database which means the code says that it does match but message displayed is wrong.

Comment: i found my mistake.