# MySQL JDBC query much faster than it should be in JMH test

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, benchmarking, jmh

I am currently trying to benchmark MySQL queries using JHM. For this, I established a connection using JDBC with a dockerized server.

My Code:

```
@Benchmark
public void testWithPreparedStatement(Blackhole bh) throws SQLException {
    PreparedStatement st = connection.prepareStatement(query);
    st.setString(1, "Parameter1");
    st.setString(2, "Parameter2");
    bh.consume(st.executeQuery());
    connection.commit();
    st.close();
}
```

These are the results of the tests:

```
# Warmup Iteration   1: 2.318 ms/op
Iteration   1: 2.038 ms/op
Iteration   2: 1.972 ms/op
Iteration   3: 1.908 ms/op
Iteration   4: 2.000 ms/op
Iteration   5: 1.960 ms/op
Iteration   6: 1.939 ms/op
Iteration   7: 1.968 ms/op
Iteration   8: 1.959 ms/op
```

The query contains multiple joins and the database contains data so the benchmarks should not be so low.

The same query in DataGrip results in:

```
0 rows retrieved in 59ms (execution: 32ms, fetching: 27ms)
```

What I have tried:

- Running `RESET QUERY CACHE` and `FLUSH TABLES` in the `@TearDown` method
- Setting the `@TearDown` to `Level.Iteration`
- Setting `autoCommit` to `false` and manually commiting the query (see: code) + setting the `TransactionLevel` to `READ_COMMITTED`

The results the query returns using JDBC are correct though so it is properly executed.

Any ideas? All help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the 'issue' was related to using a `PreparedStatement`, once I switched over to a normal `Statement`, I get the same time values I get in Datagrip.

From [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3271249/difference-between-statement-and-preparedstatement) I found out that a `PreparedStatement` does "Precompilation and DB-side caching of the SQL statement" which proabably lead to the faster execution times.

So the slower code I am now using:

```
    @Benchmark
    public void testWithStatement(Blackhole bh) throws SQLException{
        Statement st = connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);
        bh.consume(rs.next());
    }
```